# How find formula to determine the number of strings containing $k$ unique symbols on a specific set

Tags: combinatorics

How can I find the formula $NU(n,k)$ to determine the number of elements with $k$ unique symbols in a set $F$. Set $F$ is defined as follows given number of symbols $n$, then $F$ contains all possible strings of size $n$. $F$ contains $n^n$ elements (strings).

For instance $NU(3,2)$ should give me $18$. If $n=3$, then there are $3^3$ strings in the entire set.

AAA,BBB,CCC (strings with $k=1$) $= 3$

AAB,AAC,ABA,ACA,BAA,CAA,CCB,CCA,CBC,CAC,BCC,ACC,BBA,BBC,BAB,BCB,ABB,CBB (strings with $k=2$) $= 18$

ABC,ACB,CAB,CBA,BAC,BCA (strings with $k=3$) $= 6$

I can see that $NU(n,k)$ when  $k=n \implies NU(n,n)$ is always $n!$

And $NU(n,k)$ when $k=1 \implies NU(n,1)$ is always $n$.

But how do I put it all together to find the formula.

Comment: The reason why the number of strings of length $3$ composed of exactly $2$ distinct elements of a set with $3$ elements is $18$ is that there are $3$ ways to select the element which appears twice, $2$ ways to select the element that appears once, and $3$ ways to select the position of the element that appears once:  $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 18$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is $$NU(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\left\{n \atop k\right\}$$ where $\left\{n \atop k\right\}$ denotes the [Stirling partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Can you see why?

Comment: Thanks sorry for the late response. I can totally see why.

Comment: @user2503480 If you found my answer useful you could accept it.